# Distribution profile not mapping correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I recently upgraded my Mac at work and I've imported my developer and deployment provisioning profile (which expires in July).

In XCode I can choose my deployment profile (which appears to be mapped correctly), yet when I go to compile the app for distribution, it chokes saying "The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any identity in any profile".

This has been driving me nuts all day. One would think you could load your profiles, sign the app, and then compile without all these headaches. To boot, this is an enterprise app that will **not** be released in the app store. Ever.

Has anyone seen this and/or know how to fix it? It's holding me up - in order for me to start deploying apps, I need to get this profile working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please paste the exact error message you are getting here

Comment: The error is "The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any identity in any profile"

Comment: What do you mean by Upgrade?

Comment: @XCoder - we reinstalled the operating system in order to upgrade XCode.

Comment: ok but how did you import the provisioning profile?

Comment: Before you reinstall the OS you should export provisioning profile though Xcode/organization/devices under library you can see TEAMS export it from there make a password then you should have upload it to your new Xcode from same address ^ enter the code, that should be it, then refresh it + provisioning profiles too, if you have done the above instruction it should be fine otherwise you need to go to IOS Provisioning Portal certificates then revoke your certificate.